# Rapid Turn Signal

Tags: toyota, corolla, turn-signal

For the last few years, my 2011 Toyota Corolla's left turn signal shared the same blinking rate as the right side. This morning the left turn signal started blinking at a more rapid pace than the right side. What could the issue be?

Comment: Welcome to the site. This used to be a sign one of the bulbs had gone out. Check **ALL** the bulbs on the left side to see if any of them has gone dark.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 you should post this as an answer - gets my vote!

Answer (score 2):

This usually means that one of the left bulb indicators has failed. Inspect front, rear and side indicators with the indicator stalk engaged in the left position and replace the offending bulb.

Comment: Hmmmm ... where have I seen this before ... yah, should have just answered the question, eh? Good on yah! +1

Comment: Usually easiest to turn on the hazard lights rather than the turn signal, as you don't need to have the key in the ignition.